# Mixing REST and JSP in Spring MVC, Cannot find JSP

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, mapping

I'm sure this is a noob question, and I've spent the better part of an hour trawling stackoverflow for an answer but nobody seems to have my case so here we go...

I have a new webapp that uses Spring MVC.  Most of the app (99%) is pure REST, so it doesn't have a "view" as such but rather simply sends JSON back down the wire, or sends an alternate HTTP Status for errors etc.

The exception is the login page which needs to be an actual JSP, but somehow the configuration I am using to map my REST controllers is leaving me in a state where normal JSP mappings fail.

Here's what I've got:

In my dispatcher servlet config, the relevant portions are:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

In my attempts to get it working, I have also added a mapping to the "HomeController" which currently just redirects to my login JSP:

```
<bean name="/" class="com.somepackage.HomeController"/>
```

Now, in the web.xml I have:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

This works fine for my RESTful controllers, which look like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/user")
public class BlahBlahController {...
```

My "HomeController", which just looks like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class HomeController extends AbstractController {
    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        return new ModelAndView("login");
    }
}
```

IS triggered when I hit the "/" url, but I get this error in the logs:

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/pages/login.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'
```

Now I get what it's saying, it doesn't know how to resolve `/WEB-INF/pages/login.jsp` (this page does exist btw), but I'm stuck as to how I need to alter things to get this to work.

I'm a little confused on how it's supposed to work.  Anyone got any clues?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters, but why have you defined the view resolver twice? Also, your `HomeController` is annotated with `@Component` instead of `@Controller`.

Comment: Oh.. lol.. yeah the duplicate is a mistake.. shouldn't matter as you said.  The @Component/@Controller distinction is well spotted, I'll change than now and try again.

(Post edited to remove these errors as problem persists)

Comment: So.. without the <bean name="/" class="com.somepackage.HomeController"/> I get the following error:

No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/] in ...

With the mapping I get the same error as before:

No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/pages/login.jsp] in...

I hate having that xml config there.. I'd prefer everything be annotation driven but regardless it is still not working for me

Comment: If you already have annotations set up for the other controller, you should be able to do that for HomeController as well. Are the controllers in the same package? Have to set up scanning of the correct packages?

Comment: The controller fires, that's not the problem.  The problem is the JSP it forwards to cannot be found.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but it seems like it's thinking that the view is actually a handler mapping, and not a JSP view. So cleaning up any configuration ambiguity would be a good start. I notice now that you're exending an `AbstractController`. What does it look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK.. I found the answer, it's the url-pattern in the dispatcher config.

Instead of:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

It should be

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I had actually found this answer elsewhere and tried it but "thought" it wasn't working, then realized the reason I thought this was unrelated to the root cause.

No idea why this would work and the other wouldn't.. but one problem at a time...

Answer (score -1):

Put RequestMapping at the method level, I tried at my code and it worked. You don't need to define HomeController bean if you are using @Controller and having a proper "context:component-scan"

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(value = "/") 
protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    return new ModelAndView("login");
}
```

you can also use below code if you just want to redirect a login view for all "/" access.

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="login"/>
```

Checkout the [mvc show case](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase) project from github for a helpful reference.

Comment: As I mentioned in the previous comments, the problem is not that the controller is not found, it is and it fires.  The problem is that the JSP it forwards to cannot be found. 

No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/pages/login.jsp] in DispatcherServlet

Comment: Well you have correctly modified url-pattern which I had missed. you may appreciate spring's ease of use by just adding <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="login"/> you don't need to write any controller

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The controller in the post was just an example.  There is more code that goes there but I thought it might be important to show the precise conditions in which the problem was occurring.  I do use the view-controller element elsewhere and I agree it is indeed very useful.